# Does IdentityServer 4 support Win auth with multiple Active Directories?

Tags: active-directory, identityserver4, windows-authentication

I've been reading the docs for Identity Server 4 ([here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html?highlight=windows)) and it supports Windows Authentication and Active Directory.

Does it support multiple Active Directories? 
Does it need to be configured somehow or Windows take care of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That article is talking about running your application behind IIS. It's actually IIS performing the Windows Authentication, then passing the credentials to your application.

The answer to your question is "it depends". The server has to be able to authenticate your credentials. It *can* be from a different domain, but only if the domain your server is joined to trusts the domain the user account is on.

So if your server is joined to `DOMAIN1`, which is in an AD forest that has three domains: `DOMAIN1`, `DOMAIN2`, and `DOMAIN3`, then anyone with accounts on `DOMAIN1`, `DOMAIN2`, or `DOMAIN3` can authenticate to your application.

Or if your server is joined to `DOMAIN1`, and `DOMAIN1` has an explicit trust with `DOMAIN4` (in a different AD forest), then users from `DOMAIN4` can log in.